# Difference between grails-2.3.7 controler and grails-1.2 controller generated by 'generate-all' command

Tags: grails

I have been learning grails from an old book 'GettingStartedwithGrailsFinalInfoQ' which uses grails-1.2 and there are some differences.Like generated GSPs,Controller(generate-all). And I am using grails-2.3.7, so can someone pointout the difference/replacements in the different version ? I am a bit confused.

grails-2.3.7 doesn't have `def list` and there is code difference in `def index` and `def show` and other differences in the Controller as well as GSP codes.

Comment: Instead of learning an ancient version of Grails and trying to figure out what's new, why not get a current book? Lots of good options at https://grails.org/wiki/Books

Comment: Well, thanks for great advice, but I am about to finish this book, only one chapter is left and I got some difference.

Comment: If you are using grails 2.3.7, why in the world are you using a reference book for grails 1.2? If there is a difference, just accept the grails 2.3.7-generated code as correct, and understand what it does. As Burt mentioned, use a correct reference if you want explanatory text ,or just look at the grails doc online. Your book is telling you incorrect information. I don't think anyone can explain all the differences between 1.2 and 2.3.7 in a short, simple manner. You could read the release notes for all the intervening versions. Much simpler to just learn the new grails.

Comment: Thank You. I will continue from next book.